# Mutliple day VEVENT crashing in iCal

Tags: ios, iphone, icalendar

I've created an ICS file for users to subscribe to their calendar on their iPhone and other Calendar software. Everything seems to be working great, no issues anywhere.

The only problem I keep running into is that on the iPhone all events that are covering more then 1 day crash when you try to look at them. Calendar on the Mac or Google Calendar shows them just fine. Am I overlooking anything stupid?

Here's an example, first event crashes, second event works just fine:

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20141219T170203Z
UID:kSChyB7KjAHQxS0eUSQ_5-Jm05PfeFqa4F4JKW17-IswWXqUFPRGiBGV
DTSTART:20141226T190000
DTEND:20141227T021500
DESCRIPTION:x
LOCATION:x
SUMMARY: x
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20141219T170224Z
UID:HdhK2VXwuLuTxeGKJtCkeUTPElV5DMMawMMeG6Wj_1MAOqeAIL1rR3yj
DTSTART:20141226T100500
DTEND:20141226T164500
DESCRIPTION:x
LOCATION:x
SUMMARY:x
END:VEVENT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say the date start and date end are ill formatted. Formatting the date start and end as follows

```
DTSTART;TZID=Europe/Amsterdam:20150101T000000
```

should make them work. A datetime without a timezone is a weird thing :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what type of event you want to represent here but it is generally not advisable to use floating time (for your DTSTART/DTEND).

If your events are not recurring you probably want to use date in zulu.

See https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.5 for the definition of floating time versus zulu time.

This might not solve your crash issue but it should help interoperability at least.